# This OFFSET FETCH command passes validation but produces no results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have to connect accounts to users, and in doing so I have ensure I'm selecting the right account to ensure eligibility and do this with multiple accounts.  The following code passes validation but yields no results.

I already have a list of the CustomerNumbers on the table that are the PK.

---

```
SELECT
x.CustomerNumber,
a.ACC_AccountId

FROM Eligibles x

LEFT JOIN
    ACCOUNTS a
    ON x.CustomerNumber = a.ACC_CustomerNumber
    ORDER BY a.ACC_LIVEcode ASC,
         a.ACC_Limit DESC,
         a.ACC_Amount DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

---

I am not getting any Account ID's to populate, whereas nearly everyone should have one.

Answer (score 0):

In an ascending sort, `NULL`s are first.  So, you get the mismatches first.  Instead, add an expression so the matches are first:

```
SELECT x.CustomerNumber, a.ACC_AccountId
FROM Eligibles x LEFT JOIN
     ACCOUNTS a
     ON x.CustomerNumber = a.ACC_CustomerNumber
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ACC_CustomerNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
         aa.ACC_LIVEcode ASC, a.ACC_Limit DESC, a.ACC_Amount DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try this with no luck.  I should also mention that are no null values in this case and the LIVEcode depicts the status of that account ranging from 1 (Active) to 9 (Inactive)

Comment: @Waystone . . . The `NULL` values come from the `LEFT JOIN`.